# How to join the index value of two arraylists and make them a single list/set etc

Tags: java, selenium

Let's say I have two `ArrayList`: `Firstname {a,b,c,d}` and `SecondName {e,f,g,h}`

Now I want a list or HashMap etc. in the form `FullName{ae,bf,cg,dh}`.

Could you please help me in understanding this collections concept in Java?

below is my code

```
   import java.util.*;
 public class Collections1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList<String> FName=new ArrayList<>();
    FName.add("A");
    FName.add("B ");
    FName.add("C ");
    FName.add("D ");
    ArrayList<String> SName=new ArrayList<>();
    SName.add("E");
    SName.add("F");
    SName.add("G");
    SName.add("H");

    HashMap<ArrayList,ArrayList> FullName=new HashMap<>();
    FullName.put(FName, SName);

    System.out.println(FullName.keySet()+"-------------" 
 +FullName.values());
 }

  }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does "ae" really mean? Simple String concat? And note: a map is very different from a list; so give me map or list ... simply sounds like you really don't know what you want. That is most often a bad starting point. Clarify your requirements first. We cant do that for you.

Comment: So ae represent the complete FullName of the employee

Comment: I want the output to be 

{AE,BF,CG,DH}

Comment: That doesnt at all answer my question ...

Comment: Hey GhostCat ,i just want my expected output.it does not matter if we use List,Map etc

Comment: In addition to what GhostCat said, you should stick to name conventions in Java: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html This will make your code easy to read for everybody.

Comment: So would assembling a String using a StringBuilder in a loop be a solution?

Comment: Thanks Tim and GhostCat nice suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Collections1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList<String> FName=new ArrayList<>();
    FName.add("A");
    FName.add("B ");
    FName.add("C ");
    FName.add("D ");
    ArrayList<String> SName=new ArrayList<>();
    SName.add("E");
    SName.add("F");
    SName.add("G");
    SName.add("H");

    ArrayList<String> FullName=new ArrayList<>();

    if(FName.size()==SName.size()){
        for(int i=0;i<FName.size();i++){
            FullName.add(FName.get(i).trim()+SName.get(i).trim());
        }
    }

    for(int j=0;j<FullName.size();j++){
        System.out.println(FullName.get(j));
    }

   }

  }
```

Comment: Thanks :) it worked